# Deploying war file generated by maven on tomcat server

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am using maven in eclipse spring project,
When I run the project within eclipse( `run as -> on server`) I can access it on 
this url `localhost:8080/projectname` and when I run it using maven tomcat plugin(mvn tomcat7:run) I can access it on `localhost:8080/` but when I try to deploy the war file generated by maven in standalone tomcat server I get a beautiful  HTTP 404 status.

- I use tomcat manager app to deploy projects, by the way I have deployed successfully war file for non maven project.
- When I open my war  I note that in web-inf there are no web.xml and I  can't find my  jsp files.
  thanks ;)

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>ICAPSDASHBOARD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <!--<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

the rest is just dependencies.

Comment: you defined maven-war-plugin in your pom ? Can you show relevant maven config ?

Comment: Yes, i well add my pom.xml

Comment: How do you generate your war file?

Comment: using maven **mvn install**

Comment: So this is really a question about getting Maven to build a proper WAR file, not that Tomcat refuses to deploy it; you already know the WAR file is broken.

Comment: but don't forget that when maven deploy the project  in  embedded tomcat it use the same war file generated by himself, therefore I have  a doubt.

Comment: You are right @ChristopherSchultz it was an error in maven war plugin configuration, thank you.